# Why does my microwave kick out the internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have had a standard Internet setup in my home network for many years and my router is set to 2.4 ghz but I just recently got a new microwave and every time I use it the Internet seems to kick out only the laptops near by. If I change the frequency to 5 ghz all my computers except the newer ones will kick out because their network adapters only support 2.4 ghz. I am tired of dragging an either net cable through my house and I was wondering it there was a possible fix to this?

Comment: Thats *really* wierd - since your microwave *should* adequately shielded to prevent it. However, it DOES use the 2.4 ghz frequency to cook food, same as wifi internally so this seems plausible. An improperly shielded microwave is VERY bad tho

Comment: Would you recommend changing the channels on my router

Comment: I'd recommend having the microwave checked out, actually. You apparently accidentally bought a signal jammer.

Comment: Yea I just bought it pretty recently and I could return it. I heard this is not two uncommon for some people

Comment: I don't recommend having the microwave checked out, because doing so will probably cost as much as the microwave, without coming up with any fix. Look, I have a brand-name one which jams Wi-Fi: it's a made-in-Japan Panasonic that cost close to $200. There is nothing wrong with it; they just do that. A perfectly shielded microwave would cost a thousand bucks, be built like a bank vault, and weigh 75 pounds. The only possible market for it would be the paranoid tin foil hat crowd, and those people would first have to be dislodged from their opinion that all microwaves are the work of the devil.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my microwave kill the Wi-Fi?](https://superuser.com/questions/637594/why-does-my-microwave-kill-the-wi-fi)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, microwaves **are** the reason why 2.4GHz frequency is not licensed.

This is because first microwaves were using 2.4 GHz and it was basically impossible to regulate, this frequency was left open.

Later on, a lot of other devices started using the same frequency: 802.11b, Bluetooth, later 802.11g, then cordless phones, these days 802.11n, etc...

Of course, this led to the [tragedy of the commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons) - one common frequency is getting abused by everybody. Using new 5 GHz frequency helps a bit, but way too many devices depend on 2.4GHz being available.

Regarding your particular microwave - it is possible that you can get better shielding by replacing it, but you cannot possibly reduce this effect to 0. Also, there is no guarantee that your neighbours' microwave will have perfect shielding either.

Comment: Ok that should help il just get another microwave rather than screwing up all my laptops with new network adapters