# Tp-link tl-wr740n wifi stops working after several minutes

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My friend has a tp-link tl-wr740n router. His PC has cable connection and it's ok all the time. Unfortunately, there is a problem with wifi connection. After restarting the router he can connect to the internet with his notebook and 2 smartphones but after several minutes wifi connection stops on all devices (except cable connected PC which is fine all the time). We tried to change wifi channel, mode, and channel width and updated the firmware but it didn't help. I thought that the router is broken but our another friend has exactly the same model. He brought it and we tested it but the result was exactly the same. What could be the problem? Should we provide more information?

Comment: You could try OpenWRT, as this FW seems to solve most of the problems with this router.

Comment: [Microwave](http://superuser.com/q/637594/194694), by any chance? Jokes aside, which [hardware revision](http://www.tp-link.com/en/article/?id=46) is it? What's his [firmware version](http://www.tp-link.com/en/article/?faqid=315)?

Comment: @gronostaj Hardware version is V4. We downloaded firmware from http://www.tp-link.com.pl/support/download/?model=TL-WR740N&version=V4 . It was TL-WR740N_V4_130513_PL before and we upgraded to TL-WR740N_V4_140626_PL.

Comment: @TomBrek I don't have access to it right now, but we will try it later and let you know.

Comment: Be careful with alternative firmware, it will void your warranty and may be buggy or break the router if something goes wrong. If you want to try it anyway, I'm using DD-WRT build 23919 on WR740N v4.21 since a month and it works well (but there are some known bugs, such as 5 GHz not working). It doesn't sound like a router issue to me, though. Borrow a completely different router and check if it works.

Comment: It's weird, but on the next day my friend restarted the router and it worked fine. He had this problem for months. One day I changed config as I wrote in the main post, restarted, and it failed after several minutes. Then I wrote this question. No further changes has been made and on the next day he suprisingly told me that it started to work and it's still working. I don't understand why but I'm happy it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with this router `TP link  TL-WR740N / TL-WR740ND` but I fixed it by upgrading to the latest firmware.

The link is http://www.tp-link.in/Support/download/?model=TL-WR740N&version=V4

Please check your hardware version of the router if you install and upgrade other version then the router will crash and wont work.

After this go to http://192.168.0.1 and use admin/admin as username/password

Comment: What firmware versions have the problem, and what firmware version are you recommending as the solution?  "Latest" is a relative thing, especially if they put out a new firmware tomorrow that then reintroduces the original problem.

Comment: I have the same router with v2 hardware, upgrading the firmware didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Connect a network cable into the router. It doesn't have to be plugged into another device besides the router. This worked for me.

Comment: Do you mean just leaving an unconnected Ethernet cable dangling from the router solved your problem?  I suspect that something else is going on.  For example, moving the router and fiddling with the cables might have fixed a bad connection on another cable.

Comment: Yes, unconnected cable, sounds stupid I know. I don't think moving the router or the cable did anything as I checked the LEDs beforehand, according to the LEDs everything was OK. Weird.