# Wifi related weirdness / dropping connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I'm having some weird wifi issues at home which I cannot figure out.

My problem is that the wifi connection randomly drops and, sometimes, will not reconnect.

My home property is an apartment with 3 rooms. My broadband/wifi router is located in my lounge area. I have an office and I connect to the wifi in the lounge.

The connection drops all over the property, but what is particularly weird is that it seems the **closer** you are to the wifi, the worse the connection! The connection does drop in the office, but it's much worse in the lounge.

The broadband router is a [BT Home Hub 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BT_Home_Hub).

My laptop sees the most problems connecting. It's a 2008 MacBook Pro running Mavericks.

Other devices on the network include:

- A Chromecast, located in the lounge about 30 centimetres from wifi router, which falls off the network often.
- An iPhone 5s, which never seems to have a problem, maybe once or twice.
- An Apple Airport Express, seems ok, but I don't use it a great deal so hard to tell.

I'm at a loss about what to change or how to fix?

Comment: [How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)

Comment: Take a look at [Why does my microwave kill the Wi-Fi?](http://superuser.com/q/637594/194694), try changing router's Wi-Fi channel  (make it 1, 6 or 11, other ones only make things worse according to Cisco experiments), update router's firmware.

Comment: Thanks do you have a link for those "Cisco experiments" ?

Comment: I think someone posted the link here on Super User, but I don't remember which question it was. Something multiple routers-related, I think.